# Julia: Check if elements from one vector are within another vector

Tags: vector, julia

I would like to check if the elements in one vector are contained within another vector. In R there is the operator `%in%`.

For example the operator would do the following:

```
 [1,3,5,7,9,4] %in% [1,2,4,5,8,9,10,11] 
 # [true,false,true,false,true,true]
```

I can easily write my own only I am trying not to reinvent the wheel.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a number of built-ins that do something similar. `indexin` gives you the indices in `b` where the elements of `a` are found (0 if it is not there - this is similar to R's `match`). `setdiff` gives you the elements in `a` that are not in `b`. It is likely you'll be able to do what you want with these - constructing temporary boolean arrays for filtering is not so ideomatic in julia as in R, as it generally creates an extra, unnecessary allocation.

Answer (score 6):

Probably not so nice, but you could do:

```bash
julia> [1,3,5,7,9,4] .∈ [[1,2,4,5,8,9,10,11]]
6-element BitArray{1}:
  true
 false
  true
 false
  true
  true
```

Comment: Huh, nice broadcast trick with the extra brackets to expand the second array like an element!

Answer (score 1):

You could use an anonymous function : `map(x -> x in [1,2,4,5,8,9,10,11] ,[1,3,5,7,9,4])`
Or a comprehension : `[x in [1,2,4,5,8,9,10,11]  for x = [1,3,5,7,9,4]]`